# Nuxt 3 Error 500 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')

Tags: nuxt.js, strapi

Был рабочий проект на nuxt 3, решил попробовать библиотеку nuxt UI, после установки вылезла ошибка
После этого я удалил библиотеку, но ошибка никуда не делась. Подскажите, пож, в чем проблема? Как полечить? Не хочется переносить весь код в другой проект..

[image: скрин ошибки]